# On Safari iOS - playing youtube videos HTML5 player opens and automatically closes

Tags: ios, html, youtube, safari

I have embedded youtube videos on my website like this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YOUTUBE_ID" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And everywhere it wokrs fine, but on Safari on iOS it opens the HTML5 player with the video in full screen, and then the player `automatically` closes. No error in the console, related to this issue.

Tried on standalone page with the same video, embedded the very same way, and had no problems.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the JS files and then it played well :D ... so, I brought them back and started to remove them one by one ... and found out that the reason for the issue is `mbox.js`.

For some reason it breaks the behavior of the HTML5 video player on Safari for iOS. So ... now I'm looking for a solution for this :)

(Tried to move the `mbox.js` code in an iframe that loads in the problematic page, but it had no effect. So ... I going on with searching the solution.)